# Data structure for detecting duplicate entries efficiently

Tags: data-structures, cryptography, bloom-filters

In search of an efficient data structure to store some sort of list hash that I can compare to a value to obtain a probability of it already being in the list.

Perhaps it makes more sense defined as follows:

Given a multiset
$$X_n:=\{x_i \ | \ \ 0 \leq i\leq n\}$$
we define a singular value (or finite set of values significantly less than n).

$$ L_{X_n} = H(x_n, L_{X_{n-1}})\text{, where } L_{-1}=0$$ for some function $H$.
There also must exist another probability function $T$. Whereby,
$$m_S(a) \geq m_S(b) \implies \mathbb{E}[T(a, L_S)] \geq \mathbb{E}[T(b, L_S)]  $$
where $m_S(x)$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in $S$.

Some examples of data structures that satisfy these condtions are:

**Bloom Filters**:

Defining
$$ H(x_n, L_{X_{n-1}}) = h(x) \mathbin{\|} L_{X_{n-1}},$$

$$
  T(a, L_s) = \cases{   1       & $a \mathbin{\&} L_s = a$ \cr
                        0       & otherwise }
$$

with $h(x)$ being the bloom filter's hashing function.
We can noticce $(,_) = (,_) = 1$ for $m(a) > m(b) > 1$ since the bits are set on the first instance. Perhaps there is some room for improvement?

**Extending a bloom filter**:

By creating a tally for each bit in a Bloom Filter we can extend $T$ to account for it. Since adding a number to the multi set twice will mean that every 1-bit in the resulting will be at least 2. As an example we could create a score function $f$ that adds up the tally in places where the hash is 1 and exponentiating it by the lowest value found.
Then simply,
$$T(a, L_s)  = \frac{f(a, L_s)}{f(a, L_s) + 1}.$$
This is already very good at detecting collisions when $m(x)$ and the number of hash functions is large. Is there a better way?

Context: Assume $n$ is large, $H$ and $T$ should be constant time (independent of n).